# Javascript - Select from DropDown - Run once

Tags: javascript, php, html-select

I'm new at this and i'm asking for help. 
Here is the rundown. it's a web-shop with an P.O.S ( Point of Sale)  interface . when the cashier logs in the POS interface , i need to auto-select a category ( let's say i have two distinct categories of products, identical in products , one is for online sales and other is for the cashier . when the cashier sells a product, i don't want him to sell by mistake a product identical in name but meant for online sales. so i need to auto-select a given category and run the submit button once

This is the original code that pulls out the category lists as a drop down from the database.

```
<select class="form-control category-selector" id="cramadevapat" name="category" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('COM_POS_PRODUCTS_INPUT_SEARCH_CAT_PLACEHOLDER') ?>">
    <option value=""><?php echo JText::_('COM_POS_PRODUCTS_INPUT_SEARCH_CAT_PLACEHOLDER') ?></option>
    <?php
        foreach($items as $item){
            $selected = (isset($params->category) && $params->category == $item->category_id) ? 'selected' : '';
            echo '<option value="'.$item->category_id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$item->category_name_with_depth.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is what I've been able to do so far.

```
function  selectFromDropdown(selector, text) {
  $(selector).find('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == text) {
      $(selector).val($(this).val());
      return false;
    }
  })
}
setTimeout(function() {
  selectFromDropdown('#cramadevapat', 'Magazin Pallady')
jQuery(function(){ jQuery ('#submit').click();}); 
},500)
```

Here's what I've manage to do so far, but now the code lock in the drop down list, selects the thing I need, and then it runs it over and over again.

All I need is this to run only submit only once

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to do there but you could assign the timer to a variable and then stop the timer once it triggered:

```
myTimer = setTimeout(function() { ........

clearTimeout(myTimer);
```

Comment: hey there, txn for your response, here's the rundown. 
it's a webshop  with an POS interface . when  the cashier logs in the POS interface , i need to autoselect a category 
( let's say i have two distinct  categories  of products, identical in products  , one is  for online sales  and other is for the cashier . 
when the cashier sells a product,  i don't want him to sell by mistake a product  identical in name but  meant for online sales. 
so i need to autoselect a given category and run the sumbit button once .